# Best method to play Webm safely in iOS

Tags: swift, cocoapods, webm

I've been trying to play videos in my iOS app written in Swift. When I searched for it I found a library known as [OGVKit](https://github.com/brion/OGVKit). But, since it's beta and had many issues reported that are not closed yet, I searched again and found a pod [MobileVLCKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MobileVLCKit). I added the pod to the project successfully. But when I build it right after I add the pod there are 78 Apple Mach-O Linker Build time errors. I tried twice but the it gave the same result. I'm using 8.3.3 and swift 3. I would like to use only something stable since this app is about to be published in store.

[image: error log while building right after installing MobileVLCKit pod]

Comment: `MobileVLCKit` seems like a relatively up to date & well maintained repo, so I'm thinking i should compile just fine.  You should edit your question to show what some of the linker build time errors look like (e.g. a screenshot?).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann there are 78 errors each time I install the pod. I've added the image above.